# Is there any helper function or Package that helps in Twilio Sms flutter application

Tags: flutter, dart, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

I am trying to create a flutter application that sends SMS to relatives of an elderly person if he has not consumed his medicine on time. I was planning on using Twilio but there is not enough documentation and resources for me to implement it. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another way to do this using just the Http package

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import 'dart:convert';



void sendSMS() async {

  var cred =

      'ACCOUNT_SID:AUTH_TOKEN';

  var bytes = utf8.encode(cred);

  var base64Str = base64.encode(bytes);

  var url =

      'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACCOUNT_SID/Messages.json';

  var response = await http.post(url, headers: {

    'Authorization': 'Basic ${base64Str}'

  }, body: {

    'From': '+xxxxxxxx', //twilio number

    'To': '+15558675310',

    'Body': 'Hello world!'

  });

  print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');

  print('Response body: ${response.body}');

}
```

Using this function we can send SMS from a Twilio Number. Correct me if I'm wrong. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out this [Dart helper library for Twilio](https://github.com/mplacona/twilio-dart)?

1. Add a dependency to `twilio_dart` to your *pubspec.yaml*
2. Run `pub get`
3. Get a key and authentication code from your [Twilio console](https://www.twilio.com/console). The account is limited but free.

Now you can make a new Twilio object with your account details like so:

```
import 'package:twilio_dart/twilio.dart';

var key = "your_twilio_key";
var authToken = "your_auth_token";
var version = "2010-04-01";
//create a new twilio object
Twilio twilio = new Twilio(key, authToken, version);
```

To send a SMS with this, add

```
var from = "your_twilio_phone";
var to = "your_mobile_number";
var body = "Look ma! Dart can now send SMS's in under 15 lines";
```

and check out the [repo](https://github.com/mplacona/twilio-dart) for more!

Comment: I Already tried that package. It generates this error.


The current Dart SDK version is 2.7.0.

Because *******_app depends on twilio_dart any which requires SDK version >=0.8.10+6 <2.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because elderly_app depends on twilio_dart any which requires SDK version >=0.8.10+6 <2.0.0, version solving failed.)

Comment: @AdarshBalu try to update your app's pubspec.yaml to `environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"`

Comment: @AlexBaban It's already updated. The issue is with that package.

Comment: @AdarshBalu can you update your question and add the code you have in pubspec.yaml for your app and also pubspec.yaml for twilio_dart? I'm trying to figure out from where that `>=0.8.10+6 <2.0.0` is coming. At GitHub twilio_dart depends of `sdk: '>=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0'`.